# Algorithm for Entropy Minimization under Quadratic Constraint

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-optimization, entropy, constraints

I want to solve the following problem:
\begin{align}
    \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \quad&\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \log x_i \\
    \text{s.t.}\quad & x \succeq 0 \\
    \quad & \|Ax-b\|_2\leq c
\end{align}
Where $A$ is not full-ranked and not even square.

I tried to implement a projected proximal point algorithm but I'm having issues with the projection $P_C(x)$ of $x$ on the convex set $C=\{x\mid \|Ax-b\|_2\leq c\}$. Currently I solve the following equation by minimizing the $\|\cdot\|_2$ of the difference:
\begin{gather}
    AP_C(x) = b + (Ax-b)\min\left(1,\frac{c}{\|Ax-b\|_2}\right)
\end{gather}
And then put to $0$ all negative coordinates of $P_C(x)$.